# I wonder why the event listener isn't working? It seems like it should be working, but it isn't

Tags: javascript

I might also have other bugs in my code, too, haven't been able to test the code out properly though, because of the event listener. I'm basically making a small game that has to do with stocks, like how prices increase and decrease over time. However, this has become a problem. Can you figure out what's wrong? Thanks!

```js
const submitPurchaseInfo = document.getElementbyId("submit-purchase-info");
var priceStock = document.getElementbyId("price-stock");
var ownerStock = document.getElementbyId("owner-stock");
var stocks = [];
var moneyChange = "zero";
var Profit = document.getElementbyId("profit");
var i = 0;
var ownerExists = false;

if (Profit >> 0) {
  moneyChange = "positive";
} else if (Profit << 0) {
  moneyChange = "negative";
} else {
  moneyChange = "zero";
}

function buyStock() {
  priceStock.classList.remove("notshown");
  ownerStock.classList.remove("notshown");
  document.getElementbyId("text2").classList.remove("notshown");
  document.getElementbyId("text3").classList.remove("notshown");
  submitPurchaseInfo.classList.remove("notshown");
}
submitPurchaseInfo.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // for (i = 0; stocks[i] !== null; i++) {if (ownerStock == stocks[i]) {ownerExists = true}}
  if (ownerExists == false) {
    stocks[i] = ownerStock
  }
  ownerExists = false;
});
document.getElementbyId("addStock").addEventListener("click", buyStock);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.notshown {
  visibility: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.text-input {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: black;
}

#profit {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 95%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p id="text0"><b>Hello! Here are your stocks!</b></p><br>
<p id="text1">Hint: There are stocks you can buy or sell!</p>
<div id="addStock"><button>Buy</button></div><br>
<p id="text2" class="notshown">Price: </p> <input type="text" id="price-stock" class="text-input notshown"><br><br>
<p id="text3" class="notshown">Owner: </p> <input type="text" id="owner-stock" class="text-input notshown"><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit-purchase-info" class="notshown">
<div id="profit">$0</div>
```

Comment: Typo: `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementbyId`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case sensitive programming language. You have to write purely:

```
document.getElementById() //E,B,I in capital
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
    *, *::before, *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .notshown {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    body {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    .text-input {
        background-color: gray;
        border: 2px solid white;
        color: black;
    }
    #profit {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 95%;
        margin-top: -25%;
        color: #EEEEEE;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<p id="text0"><b>Hello! Here are your stocks!</b></p><br>
<p id="text1">Hint: There are stocks you can buy or sell!</p>
<div id="addStock"><button>Buy</button></div><br>
<p id="text2" class="notshown">Price: </p> <input type="text" id="price-stock" class="text-input notshown"><br><br>
<p id="text3" class="notshown">Owner: </p> <input type="text" id="owner-stock" class="text-input notshown"><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit-purchase-info" class="notshown">
<div id="profit">$0</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const submitPurchaseInfo = document.getElementById("submit-purchase-info");
    var priceStock = document.getElementById("price-stock");
    var ownerStock = document.getElementById("owner-stock");
    var stocks = [];
    var moneyChange = "zero";
    var Profit = document.getElementById("profit");
    var i = 0;
    var ownerExists = false;

    if (Profit >> 0) {
        moneyChange = "positive";
    } else if (Profit << 0) {
        moneyChange = "negative";
    } else {
        moneyChange = "zero";
    }

    function buyStock () {
        priceStock.classList.remove("notshown");
        ownerStock.classList.remove("notshown");
        document.getElementById("text2").classList.remove("notshown");
        document.getElementById("text3").classList.remove("notshown");
        submitPurchaseInfo.classList.remove("notshown");
    }
        submitPurchaseInfo.addEventListener("click", () => {
        //  for (i = 0; stocks[i] !== null; i++) {if (ownerStock == stocks[i]) {ownerExists = true}}
            if (ownerExists == false) {stocks[i] = ownerStock}
            ownerExists = false;
        });
    document.getElementById("addStock").addEventListener("click", buyStock);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

All instances of `getElementbyId` should be `getElementById`

```js
const submitPurchaseInfo = document.getElementById("submit-purchase-info");
var priceStock = document.getElementById("price-stock");
var ownerStock = document.getElementById("owner-stock");
var stocks = [];
var moneyChange = "zero";
var Profit = document.getElementById("profit");
var i = 0;
var ownerExists = false;

if (Profit >> 0) {
  moneyChange = "positive";
} else if (Profit << 0) {
  moneyChange = "negative";
} else {
  moneyChange = "zero";
}

function buyStock() {
  priceStock.classList.remove("notshown");
  ownerStock.classList.remove("notshown");
  document.getElementById("text2").classList.remove("notshown");
  document.getElementById("text3").classList.remove("notshown");
  submitPurchaseInfo.classList.remove("notshown");
}
submitPurchaseInfo.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //  for (i = 0; stocks[i] !== null; i++) {if (ownerStock == stocks[i]) {ownerExists = true}}
  if (ownerExists == false) {
    stocks[i] = ownerStock
  }
  ownerExists = false;
});
document.getElementById("addStock").addEventListener("click", buyStock);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.notshown {
  visibility: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.text-input {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: black;
}

#profit {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 95%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p id="text0"><b>Hello! Here are your stocks!</b></p><br>
<p id="text1">Hint: There are stocks you can buy or sell!</p>
<div id="addStock"><button>Buy</button></div><br>
<p id="text2" class="notshown">Price: </p> <input type="text" id="price-stock" class="text-input notshown"><br><br>
<p id="text3" class="notshown">Owner: </p> <input type="text" id="owner-stock" class="text-input notshown"><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit-purchase-info" class="notshown">
<div id="profit">$0</div>
```